# How to remove CSS style using condition in Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using `ng-repeat` to display education details in table-row format as below and each row is splited with `border-bottom:1px solid #337AB7;` style.

```
<div class="well row table-responsive" >
    <form name="eForm" role="form" novalidate>
       <div ng-repeat="data in blobObjEducation" ng-hide="profileFilled==false;">
           <table  class="table table-hover dataTable col-sm-8" >

                <tr ng-show="!eEditMode[$index]">
                <td class = "col-sm-6 editstyle" ng-if="!data.yoj && !yoc || !data.university ||!data.qualification && !data.specialization"><b>Enter Education details below</b></td>
                <td class ="col-sm-6" ng-show="data.yoj && data.institute &&(data.qualification || data.qualificationTxt) && (data.specialization  || data.specializationTxt) && data.yoc">
                                    <b id="universitytitle">{{data.institute}}</b>

                <br><br>
                <b class="sizefortitle">
                {{data.qualification}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                {{data.specialization}}<b class ="sizefortitle"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{data.yoj}} To {{data.yoc}}</b>  </td>
                <td  ng-show="editIconDisplay[$index]" class = "col-sm-1 editstyle pull-left" id ="editId" ng-click="edit('education', $index);"><a aria-hidden="true"><span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"  data-toggle ="tooltip" title="Edit your Qualification" data-placement ="top"></span></a></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
<style>
  .dataTable{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #337AB7;
      border-spacing: 5px;
      border-collapse: separate;
  }
</style>
```

I am using a condition that if field values are empty then it will show the row as"Enter Education details" with edit icon on top right corner (as shown in below image).

I need not to show any message, edit icon and css border-bottom.

[image]

Comment: You can use `ng-class`.

Comment: @kalai which object showing your field values, so which basis you are deciding that object is empty?

Comment: <td class = "col-sm-6 editstyle" ng-if="!data.yoj && !yoc || !data.university ||!data.qualification && !data.specialization"><b>Enter Education details below</b></td>

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-class` class directive, so that you can add conditions to your class.
Try this:-
Use `ng-class="dataTable: fieldValues !== null"`
Here 
`dataTable`:- is your class name,
`fieldValues`:- is object on the basis you have to add condition.
and check there is it null or undefined. And add condition accordingly.

In your case try like this:-

```
// if following is your condition then add like below, it just an example, you can add there proper condition.

"<td ng-class="'editstyle': !data.yoj && !yoc || !data.university ||!data.qualification && !data.specialization" ng-if="!data.yoj && !yoc || !data.university ||!data.qualification && !data.specialization"><b>Enter Education details below</b></td>"
```

Comment: Just tell me on which variable basis you have to add a condion, so I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: If field value is empty then it is considering the condition **"<td class = "col-sm-6 editstyle" ng-if="!data.yoj && !yoc || !data.university ||!data.qualification && !data.specialization"><b>Enter Education details below</b></td>"** and displaying "Enter Education details" with editicon in top right corner as  mentioned in above image.     But i need not to show this message, editicon only for this condition and need to hide border-bottom css style.   Can you please help me because i am new to angularjs

Comment: yes, but just tell me the variable or object or condition on the basis you have to hide and show your class ?, what ever condition it is you have to add that condition in `ng-class` directive

Comment: I am getting below error "angular.js:9997 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 10 of the expression [editstyle: !data.yoj && !yoc || !data.university ||!data.qualification && !data.specialization] starting at [: !data.yoj && !yoc || !data.university ||!data.qualification && !data.specialization]."

Comment: It will work just write conditions very clearly like:- 1) Classes need to be quoted (' '), 2) Avoid `!data.yoj` instead of this try to add like `data.yoj !== 'null' || 'undefined'`, after condition again used quotes like i mentioned

Comment: Ok just check this documentation may be it will clear you the idea about `ng-class` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass